# html5 form validation not working in iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, formvalidation-plugin

i'm loading a page with HTML5 validated elements, and using methods like "required" and max-length, they work on Android WebViews but not in iOS's.

Is there a way to support that and other HTML5 functions that I use? or i always have to write my own validation methods?

Comment: Here you can see what's supported by what versions of iOS: http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Comment: thank you, but safari's version on iphone 4 is 4.0.5, and for iphone 5 is 6.0, but in that page they started supporting of "required" attribute in safari 8.4?? where is that?

Comment: The version that they are referring to is the iOS version, not the Safari version.

Answer (score 1):

Safari does not fully support form validation: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

You can either write your own JavaScript-based validation, or use an [existing polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms-validation).

**Update:** [Safari 10.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_1.html) includes full interactive form validation.

Comment: I have a UIWebView loading a form with fields where the “required” attribute is set (among other form validation markup), but the form wouldn’t validate. It submits the (invalid) form. However, in Safari on the same iOS device, the form is properly validated. Does UIWebView not support these validations at all? Any hints?

Comment: @DanielPietzsch I'm no iOS/macOS developer, but [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview): "In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView." Does it work there?

Comment: @DanielPietzsch On further investigation, it seems that WKWebView doesn't do any interactive elements, such as alerts and prompts, and you need to manually handle it with [WKUIDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate).

You can use [checkValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) in JavaScript to check if inputs are valid, and then it seems like you need to manually handle the user interaction, using the WebKit UI stuff.

Comment: Thanks! That’s what I’ve just tried: refactoring the view to use WKWebView instead. It definitely works with iOS 10.3. Yay! For iOS 9 and 8, it does not. For iOS 10.0 - 10.2, I don’t know. But that’s good enough for me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in the WKWebView!
If you using Cordova, have a look at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine. It's simple to integrate.