# UIWebView ignoring form pattern/required rules

Tags: html, uiwebview

Anyone know why my iOS app that uses a UIWebView which loads a form is ignoring all the form pattern and required rules? I don't think i need to post any code, as my app has many different forms all that work fine on any other browser.

Comment: which version of iOS you are running?

Comment: iOS 11.2.1 on an iPhone 8

Comment: Can you quickly cross check some in lower versions of iOS?

Comment: I can't. I don't have other devices i can test with unfortunately.

Comment: You can download other simulators in xcode and check.

Comment: OK i downloaded the iOS 8.4 simulator, but i cant see where i can use it to test. In the drop down for simulators when i goto rum my app it doesn't show up, all i see is the various device versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking the answer is here. UIWebViews do not support form validation or pattern rules.

[html5 form validation not working in iOS UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323914/html5-form-validation-not-working-in-ios-uiwebview)